# Docker for Windows installed WSL2 without apt

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to work on a project, and the setup steps begin like this:

1. Clone the repo
2. Set up Docker
3. Run `make`

Being a Windows user, I installed Docker for Windows, and it installed WSL2 to get all the Linux stuff set up.  But when I went to run `make` from the WSL shell, it couldn't find it.  So I tried to get `make` from `apt-get`... and *that wasn't there either!*

It would appear that my WSL2 install is broken.  Unfortunately, Googling for it hasn't turned up much of use.  So how do I obtain `apt` for WSL so that I can build my toolchain?

Comment: As your WSL2 install is corrupted, how about uninstall and reinstall it? Maybe it could easily fix your `apt` related issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar happened to me: I installed Docker Desktop in Windows some months ago and it configured WSL to run behind it. However, it was WSL version 1 instead of version 2, and it did not install any Linux distro, since both apps run on top of WSL.

So please, go through the [tutorial on the manual installation of WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#manual-installation-steps) to check if all the steps are actually configured.

Before that, you can already check what version of WSL you have installed and its state, by running, in CMD or PowerShell:

```
wsl -l -v
```

After you set WSL v2 as your default version ([Step 5 of the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-5---set-wsl-2-as-your-default-version)), you can make sure that Docker Desktop uses it. For that, check [this link on the Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/), more specifically the [Install](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/#install) section.

---

Regarding the `make` part of your setup, I believe that you can do that in a system of your preference. If you want to do that on WSL, I recommend you install Ubuntu running over your WSL ([Step 6 of the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-6---install-your-linux-distribution-of-choice)).

Once you installed Ubuntu or other distro, you can run it as any other app. There, you can manage your `apt`, `make` and other installations right as in Linux :)

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Not sure where I heard this, but I had been under the impression that Ubuntu was installed automatically as part of WSL.  Now that I've got it installed, things are working as expected.